# How to easily backup home folder in ubuntu budgie 18.04

Tags: 18.04, backup, ubuntu-budgie

i want to regularly backup my home folder. Most important are Pictures, Videos and Documents folders. When i look for Backup in the menu only the disk application appears, which as far as i know are only capable of disk images. I know Ubuntu has a backup application installed by default. Does Ubuntu Budgie have something similar or do i need to install a backup application myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your **Ubuntu Software**

and install

**Déjà Dup Backup Tool**

Or if you prefer commandline

```
sudo apt-get install deja-dup
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you suggest this because Ubuntu Budgie has no backup tool or because this is your favorite backup tool?

Comment: I personal use a bash script using rsync. The deja-dup program is an easy to use program and in older ubuntu version the standard backup tool. If you are not a hacker i would prefer it